# Android Digital Clock in separate Thread

Tags: android, runnable, android-handler, android-runonuithread, android-thread

I've found some [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdBid_MfwUc) of Tihomir RAdeff that says how to develop a simple Digital Clock as part of custom View. But it is an example of how to run the Clock drawing in UI thread using Handle and Runnable.

Is it a perfect way to develop the app uses infinitelly repeating draw against to the memory usage issue and battery life preservation?

I guess the better way is to carry all heavy code into a separate thread. But all examples I found are based on the UI thread usage.

Whould you please posting any example on usage the separate thread to produce the digital clock not as widget but an activity part.

Comment: You want to keep the UI thread's processing light so it is responsive to the user, and put any heavy processing in it's own, separate thread.

Comment: I know my question is pretty simple and has a fairly obvious answer regarding of making the UI thread's processing lightness. But the main point of my quesstion, whether the Tihomir RAdeff 's tutorial is an efficient to be used for implementing the clock behaviour if the whole application is more complicated than only displaying a clock.